# How to run a code that executes in accidental closing of the program in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

This is my code in executing a code that will set the status of a user to offline if they properly close the program:

```
Private Sub frmMainForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit this application?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Exit?") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

        Update_UserStatus(iUserID, 0) 'update the Status of user to Offline

        End
    End If
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub

Public Sub Update_UserStatus(iUserID As Integer, isOnline As Integer)
    Dim strQ As String = String.Empty

    strQ = "update tbl_user set isOnline = " & isOnline & " where ID = " & iUserID & ""

    Try
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()

        cmd = New MySqlCommand(strQ, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd = Nothing


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

But how can I run this code when the program accidentally close, for example when I open the task manager and force to close the program there. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the application threadexception event

```
 Public Shared Sub Main()
 ' Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions to the event. 
      AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf ErrorHandlerForm.Form1_UIThreadException
End Sub

' Handle the UI exceptions by showing a dialog box, and asking the user whether 
        ' or not they wish to abort execution. 
        Private Shared Sub Form1_UIThreadException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal t As ThreadExceptionEventArgs)
            Dim result As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult = _
                System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
            Try
                result = ShowThreadExceptionDialog("Windows Forms Error", t.Exception)
            Catch 
                Try
                    MessageBox.Show("Fatal Windows Forms Error", _
                        "Fatal Windows Forms Error", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
                Finally
                    Application.Exit()
                End Try 
            End Try 

            ' Exits the program when the user clicks Abort. 
            If result = DialogResult.Abort Then
                Application.Exit()
            End If 
        End Sub
```

here you can find a  [Source Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception(v=vs.110).aspx) about how to use it